# oracle between query not taking end date time

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

Oracle between query ignoring end date time.

Below is my table.

```
Id   Upload Date
1   05-JUL-17 12.02.11.309000000 PM
2   05-JUL-17 12.03.34.123000000 PM
3   05-JUL-17 12.04.15.334000000 PM
```

My requirement is to fetch the files between the given date time.

```
 select * from fileupload where uploaddate between to_DATE('05-07-17 12:02:11', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') and to_DATE('05-07-17 12:04:15', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')

select * from fileupload where uploaddate between to_timestamp('05-07-17 12:02:11', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') and to_timestamp('05-07-17 12:04:15', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Both queries not returns the end date time it returns only two row.

```
Id   Upload Date
1   05-JUL-17 12.02.11.309000000 PM
2   05-JUL-17 12.03.34.123000000 PM
```

But the expected result is

```
 Id   Upload Date
    1   05-JUL-17 12.02.11.309000000 PM
    2   05-JUL-17 12.03.34.123000000 PM
    3   05-JUL-17 12.04.15.334000000 PM
```

why the end date time is not fetching when using between.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `to_DATE('05-07-17 12:04:15', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')` is equivalent to `05-JUL-17 12.04.15.000000000 PM` that comes before  `05-JUL-17 12.04.15.334000000 PM`

So the third result is not extracted because is not in the range for 334 ms.

---

To extract all the records you need to update the query not considering the milliseconds as follow:

```
 select * from fileupload 
 where  cast(uploaddate as date) 
        between to_DATE('05-07-17 12:02:11', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') 
        and to_DATE('05-07-17 12:04:15', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: then It should include this 05-JUL-17 12.04.15.000000000 PM right?

Comment: Yes, but your data pass this instant by 334 milliseconds.

Comment: is their any way to fetch third row also.by ignoring the milliseconds?

Comment: Yes you can truncate the milliseconds

Comment: can you please explain me how to truncate the milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TO_TIMESTAMP()`.. It can handle milliseconds.

`TO_DATE` doesn't handle milliseconds

Comment: to_timestamp also not working. It also fetches the same result.

Comment: Yes.. It don't..  Because you're not mentioning milliseconds in your WHERE condition. So, It will take 0's in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

`to_DATE('05-07-17 12:04:15', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')` smaller than    `"05-JUL-17 12.04.15.334000000 PM"`(because it is `05-JUL-17 12.04.15.00`), try to change `to_DATE('05-07-17 12:04:15', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')` to `to_DATE('05-07-17 12:04:16', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')`